# Windows socket WSACleanup C++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, wsastartup, wsacleanup

I am using sockets on my program. Due to I added the `WSAStartup`.
My application runs fine (It is always up till it gets a signal to stop). 
After getting the signal it stops te problem that if I write the `WSACleanup` function at the end of my program it crashes and if I remove it it terminates fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't resovle and find the problem.The application is using more than just sockets. Although Microsoft reference sais that onevery WSAStartup you must use WSACleanup, well this is not true and the system is releasing things regards that.

Answer (score 3):

This is excerpt from one of my projects.

Initialisation:

```
#if defined(WIN32)
WSADATA wsaData;
WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 0);
if (WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0) {
  LOG("WSAStartup() error");
  return false;
}
#endif

serv_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

...
```

Cleanup:

```
#if defined(WIN32)
  /* winsock requires a special function for sockets */
  shutdown(serv_socket, SD_BOTH);
  closesocket(serv_socket);
  /* clean up winsock */
  WSACleanup();  
#else
  close(serv_socket);
#endif
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried it it is not the problem.
I am not using directlry socket but using Select on sockets.

Comment: I don't see any problems with that. If on Win, you need to call WSACleanup anyways. BTW, are you using threads?

Comment: Also, I have found nice Windows sockets API reference for you - http://www.sockets.com/winsock.htm#Cleanup.

Comment: Can you post initialization and cleanup parts of your code? Maybe we will find something out if you haven't still solved this.